Boltzmann Distribution minimising free energy
I apologize in advance, if the question has already been answered in this forum before.
So, lets assume that $X$ is some real-valued random variable. Further let $$p_T(x) = \frac{\exp\left(-E(x)/T\right)}{Z}$$ denote the Boltzmann-Distribution (I know, it's technically a density) to the temperature $T \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. $Z$ is the normalisation constant, i.e. $Z = \int_x \exp(-E(x)/T) dx$ and we shall assume that $E: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is smooth and suffciently nice that all the above is well-defined.
The property of the Boltzmann-distribution I am interested in is the following: $$p_T = \arg\max_q \mathbb{E}_{x \sim q(x)}[ -E(x)] + T \mathcal{H}(q) \\ = \arg\min_q\underbrace{ \mathbb{E}_{x \sim q(x)}[ E(x)] - T \mathcal{H}(q)}_{=:F(q)}$$
where the term on the righthandside is denoted by $F$ as this pretty much looks like the free energy in physics. Further $\mathcal{H}(\cdot)$ denotes the entropy of a density and we take the argmax over all probability densities over $\mathbb{R}$.
Does the above hold true? Or does this only hold under certain assumptions? And if so, has someone a hint how to show this result? It might be pretty straight forward, but I don't see the argument.
Any help is much appreciated!

I've figured out an answer, and thought it would be nice to share.
For the sake of simplicity assume $T=1$ and denote $p_1=p$, then we can easily calculate $H(p) = \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(x)}[E(x)] + \log(Z)$ and consequently $$F(p) = \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(x)}[E(x)] - \mathbb{E}_{x\sim p(x)}[E(x)] - \log(Z) = - \log(Z).$$
Let now $q$ be any probability distribution, then we have by Jensen's inequality
\begin{align*}
\log(Z) & = \log\left( \int_\mathbb{R} \mathbb{E}_{x \sim q(x)} \left[\exp(-E(x)) \frac{1}{q(x)}\right]\right) \\
&\geq  \mathbb{E}_{x \sim q(x)} \left[\log(\exp(-E(x))) + \log(\frac{1}{q(x)})\right] \\
&= \mathbb{E}_{x \sim q(x)} \left[-E(x)\right] + \mathcal{H}(q),
\end{align*}
and thus $- \log(Z) \leq \mathbb{E}_{x \sim q(x)} \left[E(x)\right] - \mathcal{H}(q) = F(q)$. In total we have thus shown  $$ F(p) = -\log(Z) \leq F(q),$$ and the proof is complete.
